# No buffer space available

Tags: 11.10, network-manager, networking

Yesterday I've got first in my Ubuntu experience error "connect: No buffer space available" when trying to ping some host, which I do not have a connect at the moment.
The issue rises when I use wimax connection, it appears suddenly. The only way is to restart network-manager.

Before in 10.10 I didn't have this error.